# How to set a CSS Dynamic Color in VueJs 3 composition API / Vuetify?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

My project is in Vue 3 / composition API and i use vuetify to provide my UI

I want to use a color already set in a Vuetify theme variable in my CSS, like i did previously in my JS

I've already try the CSS var() but it didn't work

You can find a more detailed situation under this message

Thanks !

Hello There ! I have this template :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <div class="demo-app-sidebar-section">
        <b>Évènements totaux ({{ calendarEvents?.length }})</b>
        <!-- faire un petit cube coloré -->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b
              >Évènements inscrits
              <span class="legende inscrit"></span> <!-- problem here --->
            </b>
          </li>
          <li>
            <b
              >Évènements non inscrits <span class="legende nonInscrit"></span> <!-- problem here --->
            </b>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mx-auto">
      <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" :options="calendarOptions">
        <template #eventContent="arg">
          <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
          <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
        </template>
      </FullCalendar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here, the CSS classes

```
.legende {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.legende.inscrit {
  background-color: #03dac6; /*problem here*/
}
.legende.nonInscrit {
  background-color: #e95196; /*problem here*/
}
```

In an another file I have the theme set like this :

```
const themeLight: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    background: "#F2F0F1",
    surface: "#FFFFFF",
    primary: "#E95196",
    "primary-darken-1": "#3700B3",
    secondary: "#03DAC6",
    "secondary-darken-1": "#018786",
    error: "#B00020",
    info: "#2196F3",
    success: "#4CAF50",
    warning: "#FDBB37",
  },
};

// Définition du thème sombre
const themeDark: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: "#121212",
    surface: "#212121",
    primary: "#6B89C9",
    "primary-darken-1": "#3700B3",
    secondary: "#03DAC6",
    "secondary-darken-1": "#018786",
    error: "#B00020",
    info: "#2196F3",
    success: "#4CAF50",
    warning: "#FDBB37",
  },
};
```

How can I use the `vuetify.theme.current.value.colors.secondary,`
like that :

```
const calendarEvents = eventResult.map((event) => {
  let isInscrit = ref(
    event.users?.find((userV) => userV.email === user?.value?.email) !==
      undefined
  );

  if (isInscrit.value) {
    return {
      id: event.id,
      title: event.name,
      start: event.date,
      backgroundColor: vuetify.theme.current.value.colors.secondary, // Set green background for registered users
    };
  } else {
    return {
      id: event.id,
      title: event.name,
      start: event.date,
      backgroundColor: vuetify.theme.current.value.colors.primary, // Set pink background for non-registered users
    };
  }
});
```

But in my CSS

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The Vuetify colors are available in CSS variables, it's always the color name prefixed with `--v-theme-`, i.e. `--v-theme-primary`, `--v-theme-secondary` etc. They contain RGB values, so you need to put them into `rgb()` to retrieve the color definition:

```css
  background: rgb(var(--v-theme-primary));
```

```js
Vue.createApp({}).use(Vuetify.createVuetify()).mount('#app')
```

```css
.vuetifyPrimary{
  background: rgb(var(--v-theme-primary));
}

.vuetifySecondary{
  background: rgb(var(--v-theme-secondary));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <div class="vuetifyPrimary">has primary background</div>
      <div class="vuetifySecondary">has secondary background</div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

For text and background color, it might be easier still to use CSS classes provided by Vuetify, i.e. `text-primary` or `bg-primary`.